# Many row corresponding to the same date, how to compute sum of the values of a column corresponding to such column

Tags: python, pandas, average, analysis

I have the following DataFrame:

```
Date          Cleaned tweets    Polarity    Subjectivity
2018-05-23    .......            0          0
2018-05-23    .......            1          1
2018-05-23    .......            1          1
2018-05-23    .......            0          0
2018-05-23    .......            0          1
2018-05-24    .......            1              0
2018_05_24.   .......            0              0
```

what i would like to do is to get the average of the polarity and the average of the subjectivity score for each day in such way

```
Date        Cleaned tweets  Polarity    Subjectivity
2018-05-23    ........          (0+1+1+0+0)/5   (0+1+1+0+1)/5
2018-05-24.   ........          (1+0)/2          (0+0)/2
```

How can i do it? is there a way to do it?

Comment: `df.groupby('Date').Polarity.mean()`

Comment: `df.groupby('Date').agg({'Polarity': 'mean', 'Subjectivity': 'mean'})`

Comment: @warped should be `'mean'`

Comment: True. edited it!

Answer (score 2):

#### `resample`

```
df.resample('D', on='Date').mean()

            Polarity  Subjectivity
Date                              
2018-05-23       0.4           0.6
2018-05-24       0.5           0.0
```